# Membership in the Great Assembly

Tags: anshei-knesset-hagedolah

Who picked the 120 Men of the Great Assembly (Anshei Knesset HaGedolah - אַנְשֵׁי כְּנֶסֶת הַגְּדוֹלָה‎), who were rabbis, scribes and prophets?  Ezra by himself?  A group of leaders?  Perhaps their merit, but someone must have had the final say.  It lasted two centuries, so did they choose their successors by majority vote?  Were the people consulted?

Answer (score 2):

The Rambam, in the introduction to *Mishneh Torah* maintains that Ezra led the Great Assembly (i.e., בֵּית דִּינוֹ שֶׁלְּעֶזְרָא). As for details about successors, check out R. Reuven Margaliot's book, *Yesod HaMishna*. There is a whole chapter on the Great Assembly, which includes this bit (pp. 38-39):

> כאשר נפטרו אחרי כן לחיי עד אחדים מחברי הכנסת הגדולה לא הוסיפו למנות במקומם, היו ימים שמספר חבריה היו מאה ואחרי כן שמונים ושמונה, הם שהכריעו לכלול מגילת אסתר בכתבי הקודש ראה ירושלמי מגילה פ"א ה"ה, כן פחתו במנין עד שחזרו למנין שבעים שאז במות אחד מהם מינו חבריו במקומו אחד מחכמי הדור והיתה מנויית אותו חכם שוב ביפוי כח כלל ישראלי שבידיהם ולא יכלו אחרים מחכמי הדור לומר אנחנו למודי ה' אנו הזקנים כי מנויית חברי הב"ד הגדול היתה בכח סמיכת אנשי כנסת הגדולה, ואחריהם שיירי כנה"ג - שנקרא כן מני שהתחילו פוחתין ממנין מאה ועשרים - חברי הב"ד אשר בדור השני נתמנו בהחלטת אנשי כנה"ג וכן נתמנה כל אחד מחכמי הדור השלישי ע"פ הוראת זקני הדור השני וזו התיחדותם של הנמנים מחדש לראשי כל חכמי הדור ואין אפשריות לערער על התמחותם, ונתכנה המוסד העליון הזה בשם ״שיירי כנסת הגדולה״ מאות בשנים אחרי תקופת עולי בבל לאשר זו היתה יפוי כחם להכריע בכל דבר דת ודין
>
> When members of the Great Assembly did not continue to appoint positions in place of those who died, there were days when the number of its members was one hundred and then eighty-eight, which included those who decided to incorporate Megillat Esther into the Tanakh (see Yerushalmi Megilla 81 #5). The Assembly decreased in size until they returned to a quorum of seventy, at which point, once someone died, his colleagues appointed in his place one of the great sages of that generation and that person had the authority to act on behalf of Israel. And other sages of that generation could not say, "We are also Hashem's disciples, we are elders," because the number of members of the great tribunal was by virtue of the ordination of the members of the Great Assembly, followed by the "Remnants of the Great Assembly," so called once they started decreasing from one hundred and twenty. The members of the tribunal in the second generation were appointed by a decision of the members of the Great Assembly, and so each of the sages of the third were appointed according to the instruction of the sages of the second generation. This was the association of those who were re-appointed as heads of all of that generation's sages, and it was not possible to challenge their expertise. This great institution was called the "Remnants of the Great Assembly" hundreds of years after the Babylonian exile, which had authority to decide on matters of religion and law.

Comment: So:  Ezra picked the first generation, then each generation picked the next by majority vote?